# Pass multi-selection combobox values to another table

Tags: database, ms-access, vba

I am working on a database of training records, which requires the date when a particular training is done. I am currently implementing this through a "Training Log" table which is updated every time the main "Employees" table is updated (through a form). I am currently able to pass the persons ID and the date completed by this code

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO Training_Log (ID,QMS_Training,DateTrained)VALUES (" &    ID.OldValue & ",'" & QMS_Training.OldValue & "','" & DateGiven.OldValue & "');"
```

However when I add the Training field, (which is a multi-select combobox) I get a type mismatch error. Does anyone know a way to pass this? I've tried a few other ways of adding the value to this statement, e.g. taking out the value before, but this is proving impossible. any help you could give would be much appreciated!

UPDATE: Reworked slightly and it seems you cannot have a multiselect field in an INSERT INTO query. Any other ideas of how to do achieve the same result would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest way to fix was to just scrap the use of a multiple selection combobox and instead use a relational table for personID and QMS_Training. then use

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO REL_people_QMS (People, QMS_Training) VALUES (" & ID & ",'" & QMS_Training & "');"
```

Moral of the story: Avoid multi-value comboboxes!

Answer (score 0):

One Simple way is to form a `Comma separated string` out of all the selected values and insert the string

```
For i = 0 To Me.MyComboBox.ListCount - 1
 If Me.MyComboBox.Selected(i) Then
   myString = myString & Me.MyComboBox.Column(boundColumnZeroBasedIndex, i) & ","
 End If
Next I
myString = Mid(myString,1,Len(myString) - 1)
'Insert myString into the table
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work as the query doesn't accept a string value, or any form of CSV